# How to loop through all objects in JSON array and create new variable with selected objects

Tags: jquery, html, json, ajax

I am bringing in a JSON file with AJAX and Jquery using the Get method. I would then like to loop through each array, select the titles of each object and then create a new variable for them to be used later.

I tried to use the .each method, but I can't seem to get it right. Hopefully someone with a bit more knowledge than me can help. I would really appreciate it.

I have attached a link to the JSON file.

CODE -

```js
function getAllCat() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET'
        , url: 'http://www.capetownetc.com/api/get_category_index/'
        , data: {
            get_param: 'value'
        }
        , dataType: 'json'
        , success: function postCat(data, i) {
            var cat1 = data.categories[i].title;
            console.log(cat1);
        }
    });
}

getAllCat();
```

Here is a link to the JSON file -

[JSON FILE](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=78514707456600072831)

Comment: Where is the `.each()` in your code example?

Comment: try to use anonymous `function`  at `success:` and simple `for` loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var catNames = {};

function getAllCat() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET'
        , url: 'http://www.capetownetc.com/api/get_category_index/'
        , data: {
            get_param: 'value'
        }
        , dataType: 'json'
        , success: function(data) {
            $.each(data.categories, function(key, item){
                catNames[key] = item.title;
            }); 
        }
    });
}
```

As you can see i create an empty object and then i loop on the categories with `$.each` and assign the title of each one to the `catNames` object.

`catNames` could also be an array and you would add values into it with `Array.push()`

BTW when passing a callback you should either declare your function elsewhere, put it in a variable and pass it like this `success: nameOfMyFunction` (notice that there are no call parentheses just the name of the variable).

If you want to pass it without previously declaring it it should be anonymous:
`success: function(){}`

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I appreciate the help. This worked really well, and you at least explained how everything works which gives me an understanding rather than just having the right code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple for loop on the JSON result.

```js
function getAllCat() {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'http://www.capetownetc.com/api/get_category_index/',
    data: {
      get_param: 'value'
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function postCat(data) {
      if (data && data.categories) {
        for (var j = 0; j < data.categories.length; j++) {
          var cat1 = data.categories[j].title;
          console.log(cat1);
        }
      }
    }
  });
}

getAllCat();
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i=0;i<data.categories.length;i++){
var catTitle=data.categories[i].title;
}
console.log(catTitle);
```